# Apply function to dataset when function calls from two sources

Tags: r, apply

I have a function that I want to apply to a dataset, but the function also uses global variables as arguments as these variables are needed elsewhere.

With this reduced example I want to apply 'pterotest' to the rows of 'data'. This test case works when the function is given V as a vector, and M and g as a single value.

```
df<- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 3))
row.names(df) <- c("Apsaravis_ukhaana", "Jeholornis_prima", "Changchengornis_hengdaoziensis")
colnames(df) <- "M"
mass_var <- c(0.1840000, 1.6910946, 0.0858997)
df$M <- mass_var

V <- seq(0.25,30, by = 0.05)
g <- 9.81

pterotest <- function(V, M, g) {
    out1 <- M*g
    out2 <- V*M
    return(list(V, out1, out2))
}

apply(df,1,pterotest, M = "M", g = g, V = V)
```

However, all I get is an error of the form:

Error in match.fun(FUN) : '1' is not a function, character or symbol

EDIT: Turning this on it's head, what I could do would be to run a loop over each row, using the multiple columns as different arguments to the function, but with a 4.2M line dataset I feel vectorising might be quicker...

Comment: Is this what you want? `apply(df, 1, pterotest, g = g, V = V)`

Comment: Thanks! I think this works where df only has one column, but not my generalised case where it has multiple columns that need to feed into the function.

Comment: Then try this: `apply(df["M"], 1, pterotest, g = g, V = V)`